# Looping over a dynamic range in Google apps script to replace certain values

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script

I've been getting problems trying to reference a dynamic range in google sheets to apply my function to: essentially replacing special characters and empty cells within a given data range with 0s, works perfectly if I gave it a static range but cant seem to do a dynamic one. Thanks alot  for any help offered

Code thus far:

```
function replaceValues() {

var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

var lastRow = sheet1.getDataRange().getLastRow()

var firstRow = sheet1.getDataRange().getRow("B2")

var targetValue1 = '-'

var targetValue2 = ''

var targetValue3 = '$'

var subValue = 0

  for(var i =0; i=targetValue1; i++); {
   var valueRng = sheet1.getRange(firstRow,lastRow);
   var newValues = valueRng.getValues()[i].setValues(subValue);


 }
}
```

Comment: `getRow()` function takes no arguments. It's not error, though. But `targetValue1` variable is a string '-', not a number, the condition `(var i=0; i=targetValue1; i++)` doesn't make sense. `var valueRng = sheet1.getRange(firstRow,lastRow)` it gives you single cell range. `valueRng.getValues()[i]` it gives you a content of the range (not a range). The content has no method `setValues()`. So it shouldn't work at all.

Comment: Dynamic range? Sounds cool. But I failed to understand -- what is that? Range is range. You can get a range anytime with the `getRange()` method. Then you can find and replace the data inside that range. Where the 'dynamic range' is in this scheme?

Comment: Hey Yuri, thanks much for the assistance "dynamic" range  refers to a range where data is constantly added to or removed from(e.g h2:G4 become h2:G6 when new data is added) the function should only apply to that range whether info is deleted or added, hope that makes sense.

Comment: Not really. I still see no problem to use the common way: `sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn())` Probably you need `2,2` instead of `1,1`, it's hard to tell from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Select the range before going the the menu and executing the function or build a modeless dialog and you can make the selection and capture on the custom dialog with a button click.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: What kind of miracle is this? Some Add-on? A have no such menu in my Spreadsheet.

Comment: That's a dialog that I wrote to create SO tables from spreadsheets.  I provided that code for it in a  recent question that I asked just to provide the code to others.

Comment: https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/generatemarkdowntable/23306117760

Comment: I prefer to roll my own.

Comment: Thanks alot cooper!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a range, you can do search and replace inside it this way:

```
range.createTextFinder('aaa').replaceAllWith('b');
```

Or with RegExp:

```
range.createTextFinder('a+').useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith('b');
```

I still don't understand what exactly you're trying to gain. So here is a guess how your script might look like:

```
function replaceValues() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var range = sheet1.getDataRange(); // is the range dynamic enough?

  // replace '$' and '-' with '0'
  range.createTextFinder("[\$-]").useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith('0');

  // replace '' with '0'
  var data = range.getValues();  
  data.forEach((row,r) => row.forEach((cell,c) => 
    data[r][c] = data[r][c].toString().replace(/^$/,'0')));
  range.setValues(data);
}
```